# What information is needed for this JustUno embed code?

Tags: sales-order, order-success-page

I am completely new to Magento 2 and programming in general. I am trying to integrate JustUno with Magento 2 and there is a script I can embed on the success page to track conversions. Below is the code:

```
<script data-cfasync="false">
    window.juapp = window.juapp || function () { (window.juapp.q = window.juapp.q || []).push(arguments) }

    /*
    Replace the [order ...] portions below with the actual order information.
    You can omit any of the attributes that you don't have values for other then the order id and order total.
    */

    juapp(
        'order',
        '[order id]',
        { total: [order total], subtotal: [order subtotal], tax: [order tax], shipping: [order shipping], currency: 'USD' }
    );

    /*
    You will need to repeat this line of code for each item in the order.
    Replace the [item ...] portions below with the actual item information in order.
    You can omit any of the attributes that you don't have values for other then the item id and quantity.
    */

    juapp(
        'orderItem',
        '[item id]',
        { name: '[item name]', quantity: [item quantity], price: [item price], color: '[item color]', size: '[item size]' }
    );

    /* end of repeat section */
</script>
```

I am not sure of what codes or syntax to use. Any help or guidance is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You can refer this extension https://www.magepal.com/help/docs/success-page-miscellaneous-scripts-magento-2/